# Instagram oAuth login fails with 403 Forbidden error using C# desktop app

Tags: c#, api, oauth, instagram

I am developing my Instagram desktop app and I can't authorize user because of 403 Forbidden error.

I am stuck in getting the response from the login POST-request.  My POST-string looks like so:

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken=98d25eec9c3d1a6935e5a491ff2fa543&username=myname&password=mypassword
```

and this is how i am forming my request:

```
        Uri url = new Uri
        ("https://instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/oauth/authorize/?client_id=" +
        instagramClient_id + "&redirect_uri=" + instagramRedirectUrl +
        "&response_type=token");

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.CookieContainer = cc;
        request.Method = "POST";

        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.KeepAlive = true;

        byte[] sentData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        request.ContentLength = sentData.Length;

        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(sentData, 0, sentData.Length);
        }

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

The result is - 403 Forbidden. Can't find out what am i doing wrong.

I can't help mentioning the fact that I have tested some other ways to complete the authorization and noticed that Google Chrome recieves much more cookies then C# request when working with Instagram. So far my desktop app doesn't receive a "sessionid", "__qca", "__utma", "__utmb", "__utmc", "__utmz", "ccode" and "user_segment" cookies. But it recieves "csrftoken" and "mid" cookies. Maybe that's why i'am always having a 403 error?

Answer (score 3):

Add `Referer` header with the value of the request URL.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @JNYRanger: Far as I can tell, it *does* answer (or at least attempt to answer) the question; adding a Referer header may or may not work, but it certainly does on some web auth systems. Please be more careful in clicking the auto-comments.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Fair enough, however it is a 2 year old question that doesn't quite include enough information to accurately answer it though.  True, it can potentially solve it based on the system, but to me it seems more comment worthy.

Comment: @JNYRanger: Seems like it's the sort of thing that either Instagram requires, or doesn't, and since the code clearly doesn't include it, the answer is either right or wrong: there's enough information there to evaluate it without more from the author.

Comment: I was googling for a solution to this problem and found this question. Then I did exactly like the author of the question and got the same problem - 403 Forbidden. After adding Referer header the problem was solved. So I left an answer here.

Comment: Thanks @NathanTuggy. I spent a few hours trying to tweak it and was pleasantly surprised to find this simple solution. +1 Thanks milos, if I had not seen your response, I probably wouldn't have tried it.